# Why is not there a dead lock in MemoryChannel of DataX

Tags: java, deadlock

https://github.com/alibaba/DataX

I would like to ask a question. In the MemoryChannel of DataX, both doPullAll and doPushAll will  lock. Why does it no cause a deadlock?
For example, under the initial conditions, the queue is empty, then doPullAll gets the lock first, and while-loop waits.
At this time, the doPushAll is called; it also tries to acquire the lock, but it will fail because the lock is already occupied. Thus a deadlock occurs.

But it is definitely not the case, this procedure must be normal. Why is there no deadlock?

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `doPullAll gets the lock first, and while-loop waits` how do you know it will enter the while ? Did you debug this part ?